# Loops in Python using CUDA

Tags: python, cuda, jit, numba

I am trying to solve a large set of coupled differential equations in a reasonable amount of time. This quickly becomes very slow to solve with regular Numpy as the number of equations I would like to solve is on the order 10^7 for a large amount of iterations.

This is basically a large amount of parallel matrix operations, it seemed to be a good task for the GPU. Using jit's vectorize and CUDA decorators on the equations helped speed up the code quite a bit over regular numpy. The issue I am having is that in order to make it work I am copying the data from the GPU at each step in the loop. As I understand it, this is a slow process, so if possible I would like to do this on the GPU and only copy the data back once the calculation is complete, but I am not sure how one would set up a loop like this to run on the GPU.

This is a simplified version of what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from numba import jit
from numba import vectorize
from numba import cuda


## size of matrices
N=4

## Time for integration
T=0.1
## Length of Time steps
dt=0.0001
## Number of time steps
n = int(T/dt)


##mockup initial values, real arrays are much larger
F_0 = np.array([[ 0.0, -1.74998928e-03, -1.74998928e-03,  0.0],
 [ 1.74998928e-03,  0.00000000e+00+0.00005j, -4.42925874e-19+1j,  1.74998928e-03-1j,],
 [ 1.74998928e-03,  4.42925874e-19,  0.0,  1.74998928e-03,],
 [ 0.0, -1.74998928e-03, -1.74998928e-03,  0.0]], dtype = np.complex64)


G_0 = np.array([[0.00000000e+00, 3.06247186e-06, 3.06247186e-06, 0.0],
 [3.06247186e-06, 1.0, 1.0, 3.06247186e-06,],
 [3.06247186e-06+0.0005j, 1.0, 1.00000000e+00, 3.06247186e-06-0.0004j,],
 [0.0, 3.06247186e-06+ -0.04j, 3.06247186e-06, 0.0]], dtype = np.complex64)


delta_i = np.complex64(1)



### Time derivatives of functions we want to integrate
@cuda.jit(device=True)
def dFdt(F,G,delta):
    first_factor = -2j*F
    second_factor = -1j*delta*(2*G-1)
    return first_factor+second_factor

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def dGdt(F, delta):
    prefactor = -1j
    secondfactor =(delta.conjugate())*F -delta*F.conjugate()
    return prefactor*secondfactor

#Standard RK4 for the specified equation set, all inputs are NxN complex matrices
@vectorize(['c8(c8, c8,c8,c8,c8)'], target='cuda')
def RK4_step_F(G, F, delta, dt, index):  

    G1 = dGdt(F, delta) 
    F1 = dFdt(F, G, delta)
    G2 = dGdt(F + dt/2*F1, delta)
    F2 = dFdt(F + dt/2*F1, G + dt/2*G1, delta)
    G3 = dGdt(F + dt/2*F2, delta)
    F3 = dFdt(F + dt/2*F2, G + dt/2*G2, delta) 
    F4 = dFdt(F + dt*F3, G + dt*G3, delta)
    return (F+(dt/6)*(F1 +(2*F2) +(2*F3) + F4))


@vectorize(['c8(c8, c8,c8,c8,c8)'], target='cuda')
def RK4_step_G(G, F, delta, dt, index):  

    G1 = dGdt(F, delta) 
    F1 = dFdt(F, G, delta)
    G2 = dGdt(F + dt/2*F1, delta)
    F2 = dFdt(F + dt/2*F1, G + dt/2*G1, delta)
    G3 = dGdt(F + dt/2*F2, delta)
    F3 = dFdt(F + dt/2*F2, G + dt/2*G2, delta)
    G4 = dGdt(F + dt*F3, delta)
    return (G + (dt/6)*(G1+ (2*G2) + (2*G3) + G4)) 


### Runs the integration, F_0 and G_0 are NxN matrices of initial values for the functions F and G, delta_i is the initial value of the parameter delta,
### dt is the step size and n is the number of steps
def RK4_method(F_0, G_0):
    delta = np.zeros(n+1, dtype=np.complex64)
    delta[0]= delta_i
    for i in range(n):

        
        RK4_step_G( G_0, F_0,delta[i], dt, 0, out = out_G)
        RK4_step_F( G_0, F_0,delta[i], dt, 0, out = out_F)
        F_0 = out_F.copy_to_host()
        G_0 = out_G.copy_to_host()

        delta[i+1] = np.sum(F_0)
        print("working")
        
    return delta

###copying initial matrices
G_cuda = cuda.to_device(G_0)
F_cuda = cuda.to_device(F_0)

##defining matrices
out_F = cuda.device_array(shape=(N,N), dtype=np.complex64)
out_G = cuda.device_array(shape=(N,N), dtype=np.complex64)


##start calculation
delta_time = RK4_method(F_cuda,G_cuda)

time = np.linspace(0, T, n + 1)

plt.plot(time[1:], delta_time[1:])
plt.show()
```

I am wondering how I would set up a loop like this without having to copy the data back and forth?

My experience is pretty much entirely in Python, so CUDA is still somewhat unfamiliar to me.

Edit: included more complete code

Comment: I would suggest providing a complete code. It shouldn't require much more than what you have shown here.  I'd rather not play 20 questions and ask you what the definitions of `out_F`, `out_G`, `delta_i`, and also the sizes of all these things and how exactly you are calling the `RK4_method`.  Just a suggestion.  Do as you wish.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the post with something more complete. I could post the complete code as I am running it, but I am not sure if it would make things more clear or less clear as it is much longer and the equations themselves are a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

This should have been a fairly straightforward set of changes to do what you want.  Unfortunately, numba `vectorize` seems to have a [characteristic that complicates things](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/6237).  So we'll have to put extra plumbing in place to achieve the goal.  Related to this, the overall code complexity might be reduced if everything were just converted to `@cuda.jit` kernels, but since your realization focuses on `@vectorize`, I'm going to try to stay as close as possible to that, although I will need to use one numba CUDA kernel, eventually.

The goal is to be able to execute your for-loop with a set of back-to-back kernel calls, with the smallest amount of data transfer (host->device or device->host), during the loop processing.

Before we get to the changes needed to achieve the goal, it would probably be useful/instructive to run your code as-is using a profiler, to get an idea of the "unnecessary" copying on each loop iteration, that we are attempting to avoid.  To keep this simple we'll reduce the loop iterations to just 2.  We'll also remove the plotting, since we're interested in code profiling, not results:

```
$ cat t39.py
import numpy as np
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from numba import jit
from numba import vectorize
from numba import cuda


## size of matrices
N=4

## Time for integration
T=0.1
## Length of Time steps
dt=0.0001
## Number of time steps
n = int(T/dt)


##mockup initial values, real arrays are much larger
F_0 = np.array([[ 0.0, -1.74998928e-03, -1.74998928e-03,  0.0],
 [ 1.74998928e-03,  0.00000000e+00+0.00005j, -4.42925874e-19+1j,  1.74998928e-03-1j,],
 [ 1.74998928e-03,  4.42925874e-19,  0.0,  1.74998928e-03,],
 [ 0.0, -1.74998928e-03, -1.74998928e-03,  0.0]], dtype = np.complex64)


G_0 = np.array([[0.00000000e+00, 3.06247186e-06, 3.06247186e-06, 0.0],
 [3.06247186e-06, 1.0, 1.0, 3.06247186e-06,],
 [3.06247186e-06+0.0005j, 1.0, 1.00000000e+00, 3.06247186e-06-0.0004j,],
 [0.0, 3.06247186e-06+ -0.04j, 3.06247186e-06, 0.0]], dtype = np.complex64)


delta_i = np.complex64(1)



### Time derivatives of functions we want to integrate
@cuda.jit(device=True)
def dFdt(F,G,delta):
    first_factor = -2j*F
    second_factor = -1j*delta*(2*G-1)
    return first_factor+second_factor

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def dGdt(F, delta):
    prefactor = -1j
    secondfactor =(delta.conjugate())*F -delta*F.conjugate()
    return prefactor*secondfactor

#Standard RK4 for the specified equation set, all inputs are NxN complex matrices
@vectorize(['c8(c8, c8,c8,c8,c8)'], target='cuda')
def RK4_step_F(G, F, delta, dt, index):

    G1 = dGdt(F, delta)
    F1 = dFdt(F, G, delta)
    G2 = dGdt(F + dt/2*F1, delta)
    F2 = dFdt(F + dt/2*F1, G + dt/2*G1, delta)
    G3 = dGdt(F + dt/2*F2, delta)
    F3 = dFdt(F + dt/2*F2, G + dt/2*G2, delta)
    F4 = dFdt(F + dt*F3, G + dt*G3, delta)
    return (F+(dt/6)*(F1 +(2*F2) +(2*F3) + F4))


@vectorize(['c8(c8, c8,c8,c8,c8)'], target='cuda')
def RK4_step_G(G, F, delta, dt, index):

    G1 = dGdt(F, delta)
    F1 = dFdt(F, G, delta)
    G2 = dGdt(F + dt/2*F1, delta)
    F2 = dFdt(F + dt/2*F1, G + dt/2*G1, delta)
    G3 = dGdt(F + dt/2*F2, delta)
    F3 = dFdt(F + dt/2*F2, G + dt/2*G2, delta)
    G4 = dGdt(F + dt*F3, delta)
    return (G + (dt/6)*(G1+ (2*G2) + (2*G3) + G4))


### Runs the integration, F_0 and G_0 are NxN matrices of initial values for the functions F and G, delta_i is the initial value of the parameter delta,
### dt is the step size and n is the number of steps
def RK4_method(F_0, G_0):
    delta = np.zeros(n+1, dtype=np.complex64)
    delta[0]= delta_i
    for i in range(2):


        RK4_step_G( G_0, F_0,delta[i], dt, 0, out = out_G)
        RK4_step_F( G_0, F_0,delta[i], dt, 0, out = out_F)
        F_0 = out_F.copy_to_host()
        G_0 = out_G.copy_to_host()

        delta[i+1] = np.sum(F_0)
#        print("working")

    return delta

###copying initial matrices
G_cuda = cuda.to_device(G_0)
F_cuda = cuda.to_device(F_0)

##defining matrices
out_F = cuda.device_array(shape=(N,N), dtype=np.complex64)
out_G = cuda.device_array(shape=(N,N), dtype=np.complex64)


##start calculation
delta_time = RK4_method(F_cuda,G_cuda)

#time = np.linspace(0, T, n + 1)

#plt.plot(time[1:], delta_time[1:])
#plt.show()
$ nvprof --print-gpu-trace python t39.py
==30045== NVPROF is profiling process 30045, command: python t39.py
==30045== Profiling application: python t39.py
==30045== Profiling result:
   Start  Duration            Grid Size      Block Size     Regs*    SSMem*    DSMem*      Size  Throughput  SrcMemType  DstMemType           Device   Context    Stream  Name
319.56ms  1.4080us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  86.698MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
319.98ms  1.0560us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  115.60MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
321.38ms  1.0240us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  119.21MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
321.78ms  1.0240us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  119.21MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
322.17ms  1.0240us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  119.21MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
491.96ms  7.3290us              (1 1 1)       (576 1 1)        56        0B        0B         -           -           -           -  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  cudapy::__main__::__vectorized_RK4_step_G$248(Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>) [84]
493.21ms  1.0240us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  119.21MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
493.61ms  1.0560us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  115.60MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
494.00ms  1.0240us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  119.21MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
653.33ms  6.2400us              (1 1 1)       (576 1 1)        56        0B        0B         -           -           -           -  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  cudapy::__main__::__vectorized_RK4_step_F$249(Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>) [130]
653.64ms  1.1840us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  103.10MB/s      Device    Pageable  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
653.73ms  1.1840us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  103.10MB/s      Device    Pageable  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
654.53ms  1.0560us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  115.60MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
654.93ms  1.0240us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  119.21MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
655.32ms  1.0560us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  115.60MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
655.72ms  1.0240us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  119.21MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
656.11ms  1.0240us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  119.21MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
656.92ms  5.8250us              (1 1 1)       (576 1 1)        56        0B        0B         -           -           -           -  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  cudapy::__main__::__vectorized_RK4_step_G$248(Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>) [169]
657.82ms  1.0560us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  115.60MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
658.22ms  1.0240us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  119.21MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
658.62ms  1.0240us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  119.21MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
659.01ms  1.0240us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  119.21MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
659.40ms  1.0560us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  115.60MB/s    Pageable      Device  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
660.03ms  5.3450us              (1 1 1)       (576 1 1)        56        0B        0B         -           -           -           -  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  cudapy::__main__::__vectorized_RK4_step_F$249(Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>, Array<complex64, int=1, C, mutable, aligned>) [213]
660.24ms  1.1840us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  103.10MB/s      Device    Pageable  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
660.33ms  1.1840us                    -               -         -         -         -      128B  103.10MB/s      Device    Pageable  GeForce GTX 960         1         7  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]

Regs: Number of registers used per CUDA thread. This number includes registers used internally by the CUDA driver and/or tools and can be more than what the compiler shows.
SSMem: Static shared memory allocated per CUDA block.
DSMem: Dynamic shared memory allocated per CUDA block.
SrcMemType: The type of source memory accessed by memory operation/copy
DstMemType: The type of destination memory accessed by memory operation/copy
$
```

Looking at the `nvprof` output above, we see that for each of the 2 loop iterations, there are 2 kernels called (one for each `vectorize` function) but there are also 10 or more copy operations.  6 of these operations are due to the aforementioned scalar/temporary array issue.

We'll employ the following techniques to improve the per-loop copy situation.  We won't be able to eliminate it entirely, but we can reduce it to a very low level that does not increase as the problem size increases.  We'll do the following:

1. Move all input arrays to the device (e.g. `F`, `G`) and leave them there.
2. Create a ping-pong structure in the loop, so that on alternating loop passes, the input arrays become the output arrays, and vice versa.  The ping-pong means we avoid copy of output to input at the end of each loop, as you are effectively doing.
3. Because of the aforementioned numba `vectorize` issue, we are going to manually convert your scalar inputs (e.g. `dt`) to device arrays that are of the same size (`NxN`) as the other input arrays.  This is the only method I found to keep numba from creating its own temporary arrays and copying those to the device on each loop iteration.
4. You have a host-based operation happening at each loop pass (`np.sum`).  We need to leave the data on the device, and use a device based operation for this.  Fortunately numba provides that via a special [reduce functionality](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/reduction.html).
5. The result of the reduction can be kept on the device, but it is still only a single value.  This puts us back into the scalar boat again.  We need to convert this back to a `NxN` array to avoid the vectorize issue already discussed.  I considered several numba "native" approaches such as `guvectorize`, but eventually gave up and used a numba cuda kernel (`@cuda.jit`) to perform the `distribute` function (taking a single value and broadcasting it throughout an array).

With those major changes, we can end up with a code that only performs a single Device to Device copy of an single `complex64` quantity per loop iteration, arising from the reduce operation in step 4, and at the end of each loop iteration a single Device to Host copy of a single `complex64` quantity to transfer the per-iteration result back to a host array.

For small test cases (e.g. `N = 4`) this makes little difference and the whole problem is trivial anyway.  For the larger test case I demonstrate below, these refactoring changes can result in a ~5x increase in overall performance.  The improvement here will vary somewhat based on the number of loops ultimately performed, and it will be heavily dependent on the problem size.

Here's a full example, you can profile it using a similar technique as indicated in the example above (I recommend reducing the loop count to something manageable, like 3) to see the difference in behavior, per loop iteration:

```
$ cat t40.py
import numpy as np
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from numba import jit
from numba import vectorize
from numba import cuda


## size of matrices
N=4

## Time for integration
T =0.01
## Length of Time steps
dt=0.0001
## Number of time steps
n = int(T/dt)


##mockup initial values, real arrays are much larger
F_0 = np.array([[ 0.0, -1.74998928e-03, -1.74998928e-03,  0.0],
 [ 1.74998928e-03,  0.00000000e+00+0.00005j, -4.42925874e-19+1j,  1.74998928e-03-1j,],
 [ 1.74998928e-03,  4.42925874e-19,  0.0,  1.74998928e-03,],
 [ 0.0, -1.74998928e-03, -1.74998928e-03,  0.0]], dtype = np.complex64)


G_0 = np.array([[0.00000000e+00, 3.06247186e-06, 3.06247186e-06, 0.0],
 [3.06247186e-06, 1.0, 1.0, 3.06247186e-06,],
 [3.06247186e-06+0.0005j, 1.0, 1.00000000e+00, 3.06247186e-06-0.0004j,],
 [0.0, 3.06247186e-06+ -0.04j, 3.06247186e-06, 0.0]], dtype = np.complex64)
#create a larger test case
N=512
F_0 = np.ones((N,N), dtype=np.complex64)
G_0 = np.ones((N,N), dtype=np.complex64)


delta_i = np.complex64(1)



### Time derivatives of functions we want to integrate
@cuda.jit(device=True)
def dFdt(F,G,delta):
    first_factor = -2j*F
    second_factor = -1j*delta*(2*G-1)
    return first_factor+second_factor

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def dGdt(F, delta):
    prefactor = -1j
    secondfactor =(delta.conjugate())*F -delta*F.conjugate()
    return prefactor*secondfactor

#Standard RK4 for the specified equation set, all inputs are NxN complex matrices
@vectorize(['c8(c8, c8,c8,c8,c8)'], target='cuda')
def RK4_step_F(G, F, delta, dt, index):

    G1 = dGdt(F, delta)
    F1 = dFdt(F, G, delta)
    G2 = dGdt(F + dt/2*F1, delta)
    F2 = dFdt(F + dt/2*F1, G + dt/2*G1, delta)
    G3 = dGdt(F + dt/2*F2, delta)
    F3 = dFdt(F + dt/2*F2, G + dt/2*G2, delta)
    F4 = dFdt(F + dt*F3, G + dt*G3, delta)
    return (F+(dt/6)*(F1 +(2*F2) +(2*F3) + F4))


@vectorize(['c8(c8, c8,c8,c8,c8)'], target='cuda')
def RK4_step_G(G, F, delta, dt, index):

    G1 = dGdt(F, delta)
    F1 = dFdt(F, G, delta)
    G2 = dGdt(F + dt/2*F1, delta)
    F2 = dFdt(F + dt/2*F1, G + dt/2*G1, delta)
    G3 = dGdt(F + dt/2*F2, delta)
    F3 = dFdt(F + dt/2*F2, G + dt/2*G2, delta)
    G4 = dGdt(F + dt*F3, delta)
    return (G + (dt/6)*(G1+ (2*G2) + (2*G3) + G4))

#code modifications begin here, the above functions are unmodified

@cuda.reduce
def sum_reduce(a, b):
    return a+b

@cuda.jit
def distribute(A, B, s):
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    if i < s:
        B[i] = A[0]


### Runs the integration, F_0 and G_0 are NxN matrices of initial values for the functions F and G, delta_i is the initial value of the parameter delta,
### dt is the step size and n is the number of steps
def RK4_method_new(F_arr, G_arr):
    delta_h = np.zeros(shape=(n+1), dtype=np.complex64)
    delta_h[0] = delta_i
    ##defining device matrices
    in_F = cuda.to_device(F_arr)
    in_G = cuda.to_device(G_arr)
    out_F = cuda.device_array(shape=(N,N), dtype=np.complex64)
    out_G = cuda.device_array(shape=(N,N), dtype=np.complex64)
    #setup "scalar arrays"
    dt_arr    = np.full((N,N), np.complex64(dt), dtype=np.complex64)
    dev_dt    = cuda.to_device(dt_arr)
    index_arr = np.full((N,N), np.complex64(0) , dtype=np.complex64)
    dev_index = cuda.to_device(dev_dt)
    delta_arr = np.full((N,N), delta_i, dtype=np.complex64)
    dev_delta = cuda.to_device(delta_arr)
    b = 256
    g = (N*N+b-1)//b
    for i in range(n):

        RK4_step_G( in_G, in_F,dev_delta, dev_dt, dev_index, out = out_G)
        RK4_step_F( in_G, in_F,dev_delta, dev_dt, dev_index, out = out_F)
        # ping-pong
        tmp_G = in_G
        tmp_F = in_F
        in_G = out_G
        in_F = out_F
        out_G = tmp_G
        out_F = tmp_F

        sum_reduce(in_F.reshape(N*N), res = dev_delta.reshape(N*N)) # causes 8 byte D->D copy
        distribute[g,b](dev_delta.reshape(N*N), dev_delta.reshape(N*N),N*N)
        delta_h[i+1] = dev_delta[0,0] # causes 8 byte D->H copy
#        print("working")
    return delta_h

def RK4_method(F_0, G_0):
    delta = np.zeros(n+1, dtype=np.complex64)
    delta[0]= delta_i
    out_F = cuda.device_array(shape=(N,N), dtype=np.complex64)
    out_G = cuda.device_array(shape=(N,N), dtype=np.complex64)
    for i in range(n):


        RK4_step_G( G_0, F_0,delta[i], dt, 0, out = out_G)
        RK4_step_F( G_0, F_0,delta[i], dt, 0, out = out_F)
        F_0 = out_F.copy_to_host()
        G_0 = out_G.copy_to_host()

        delta[i+1] = np.sum(F_0)
    #    print("working")

    return delta

##start calculation
# "warm-up runs, to get JIT compilation effects removed from timing comparison
delta_time     = RK4_method(F_0, G_0)
delta_time_new = RK4_method_new(F_0,G_0)
s = time.time()
delta_time     = RK4_method(F_0, G_0)
e = time.time()
print("old time: ", e-s)
s = time.time()
delta_time_new = RK4_method_new(F_0,G_0)
e = time.time()
print("new time: ", e-s)
for i in range(3):
    print("delta time: ", delta_time[i], " delta_time_new: ", delta_time_new[i])
#time = np.linspace(0, T, n + 1)

#plt.plot(time[1:], delta_time[1:])
#plt.show()
$ python t40.py
old time:  2.48877215385437
new time:  0.5504293441772461
delta time:  (1+0j)  delta_time_new:  (1+0j)
delta time:  (262143.98-78.64321j)  delta_time_new:  (262143.98-78.64322j)
delta time:  (1361288.4+3141394700j)  delta_time_new:  (1361289.1+3141394700j)
$
```